# creating multiple custom divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a tool where multiple boxes (divs, in this case) can be drawn by clicking and dragging the mouse. I want a new div to be drawn each time the function is called. But with what i have now, i am unable to make the height and width of the div follow the mouse's movement.

Here is my code:

```
$('#work_area').click(function(e) {
                                var increment = increment + 1; //has been defined in the global scope
                                var newBox = 'newBox' + increment;
                                var workAreaOffset = $('#work_area').offset();
                                if (ctr == 0) {

                                    var clickLocX = e.pageX; //x coordinate of origin of select box
                                    var clickLocY = e.pageY; //y coordinate of origin of select box

                                    $('<div>').attr({
                                        'class':'newBox',
                                        zIndex:'15'
                                    })
                                    .addClass(newBox) //set new class for every box
                                    .css({
                                        top:clickLocY - workAreaOffset.top,
                                        left:clickLocX - workAreaOffset.left
                                    })
                                    .appendTo('#work_area');

                                    ctr = 1; //next stage of select box method reached

                                    if (ctr == 1) {
                                        $('#work_area').mousemove(function(e){
                                            var XpageCoord = e.pageX;
                                            var YpageCoord = e.pageY;

                                            var boxHeight = YpageCoord - clickLocY; //height of the box changes with mouse movement
                                            var boxWidth = XpageCoord - clickLocX;  //width of the box changes with mouse movement

                                            $(newBox).css({
                                                height:boxHeight + 'px',          //connect mouse movement with css class for select box
                                                width:boxWidth + 'px'
                                            });
                                            ctr = 2; //next stage of the select box method reached
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (ctr == 2) {
                                    //$('.newBox').remove(); //select box removed with second click
                                    $('#work_area').css({
                                        cursor: 'default'  //cursor changed back to normal
                                    });

                                    $('#work_area').unbind('mousemove'); //mouse movement no longer has effect

                                    $(newBox).appendTo('#work_area');

                                    ctr = 0; //reset
                                }
                                else {
                                    $.noop(); //fall back
                                }
                            });
```

Please help?

Comment: It would be best if you were to put all this on jsFiddle.com, so we could see what you have now.

Comment: @BrianHoover-- here is its: http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/

my issues deal with the Select button on the top left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was REALLY close to working.  The code below will work.

The primary issue is that $(newBox) is not returning anything, because variable newBox is not a well formed jQuery selector.  And that's fine, because you're using newBox to return a unique class for each box.  All you have to do is modify the two spots where you have $(newBox) to be

```
$('.' + newBox)
```

A couple of other questions and pointers:

Why do you have the line

var increment = increment + 1; ?

this declares increment to be a local variable, so it returns 'NaN'

Also, the drag and drop blocks only work if the mouse goes from top left to bottom right.

Anyway, best of luck.

```
$('#work_area').click(function(e) {
    increment = increment + 1; //has been defined in the global scope
    var newBox = 'newBox' + increment;
    var workAreaOffset = $('#work_area').offset();
    if (ctr == 0) {

        var clickLocX = e.pageX; //x coordinate of origin of select box
        var clickLocY = e.pageY; //y coordinate of origin of select box

        $('<div>').attr({
            'class':'newBox',
            zIndex:'15'
        })
        .addClass(newBox) //set new class for every box
        .css({
            top:clickLocY - workAreaOffset.top,
            left:clickLocX - workAreaOffset.left
        })
        .appendTo('#work_area');

        ctr = 1; //next stage of select box method reached

        if (ctr == 1) {
            $('#work_area').mousemove(function(e){
                var XpageCoord = e.pageX;
                var YpageCoord = e.pageY;

                var boxHeight = YpageCoord - clickLocY; //height of the box changes with mouse movement
                var boxWidth = XpageCoord - clickLocX;  //width of the box changes with mouse movement

                $('.' + newBox).css({
                    height:boxHeight + 'px',          //connect mouse movement with css class for select box
                    width:boxWidth + 'px'
                });
                ctr = 2; //next stage of the select box method reached
            });
        }
    }
    else if (ctr == 2) {
        //$('.newBox').remove(); //select box removed with second click
        $('#work_area').css({
            cursor: 'default'  //cursor changed back to normal
        });

        $('#work_area').unbind('mousemove'); //mouse movement no longer has effect

        $('.' + newBox).appendTo('#work_area');

        ctr = 0; //reset
    }
    else {
        $.noop(); //fall back
    }
});
```